# using union in limit with pagination

Tags: php, mysql

please can someone help with mysql query with pagination for "union" select statement.using page limit and offset limit

below is my sql if am getting it wrong.

```
 $sqlQuery = "SELECT title, content, img, postlink, created_at, 'forum' as type FROM forum_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')
    UNION  SELECT title, content, img, postlink, created_at, 'music' as type FROM music_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%') UNION 
    SELECT title, content, img, postlink,created_at, 'video' as type FROM video_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%') ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT   ".($lower_limit)." ,  ". ($page_limit). "";
```

here is the full sql code in pdo

```
here is the full sql query `public function all_search($keyword, $lower_limit, $page_limit) {
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT title, content, img, postlink, created_at, 'forum' as type FROM forum_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')
    UNION  SELECT title, content, img, postlink, created_at, 'music' as type FROM music_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%') UNION 
    SELECT title, content, img, postlink,created_at, 'video' as type FROM video_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')) tab LIMIT   ".($lower_limit)." ,  ". ($page_limit). "";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $stmt->execute(['keyword'=>$keyword]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result;
}`
```

Comment: your biggest problem is that you bind keyword and not **:keyword**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM(SELECT title, content, img, postlink, created_at, 'forum' as type FROM forum_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%')
        UNION  SELECT title, content, img, postlink, created_at, 'music' as type FROM music_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%') UNION 
        SELECT title, content, img, postlink,created_at, 'video' as type FROM video_post WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', :keyword, '%'))tab LIMIT   ".($lower_limit)." ,  ". ($page_limit). "";
```

Comment: here is the full sql query

Comment: A screen capture

Comment: its outputting nothing ... form the database

Comment: try remove the limit and test

Comment: have updated the full sql code, check this topic again

Comment: OK. Does it returns without limit?

Comment: OK. Use limit and offset like on this example:

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";

Comment: The SQL query above says "return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)":